# Add higher score/penalty for consecutive result in python using loop

Tags: python, loops, math

I'm trying to write code that count final score using python. The initial code I use was:

```
initial_score = 50
result = ['T','F','T','T','T','F']
final_score = initial_score
for i in (result):
  if i == 'T':
    final_score += 10
  else:
    final_score += -5
print(final_score)
```

And the result was:

```
80
```

Now, I want to make the score/penalty to increase if the results in list are consecutive. If the results are consecutively True (T) so point added to initial_point will increase after each result (10,20,30,etc). Example:

```
initial_score = 50

result = ['T','T','T','T','T']
```

So the score for each value in the list will be `[10,20,30,40,50]` and the final score will be 200. The same goes for False (F) except the penalty will be (-5,-10,-15,etc). I also want to make constrain, if the consecutive result end it will start from the latest score/penalty. Example:

```
initial_score = 10

result = ['T','T','F','F','T','T','F','F','F','F','T','T','T']
```

And the value in the list will be `[10,20,-5,-10,20,30,-10,-15,-20,-25,30,40,50]` and the final score will be 125.

How should I do it?

Comment: Do you need the scores for each individual question or just the final result?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark the final result

Comment: Don't you want to reset the award when it is different from the previous value e.g for your second example the award should be `[10, 20, -5, -10, 10, 20, -5, -10, -15, -20, 10, 20, 30]`?

Comment: @Nick interesting idea, I will try it next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep track of the award and penalty, updating it on each right/wrong answer IFF it's the same as the previous answer.

```
def score(initial, result):
    total = initial
    award = 10
    penalty = 5
    for i, prev in zip(result, [None] + result):
        if i == 'T':
            if i == prev:
                award += 10
            total += award
        else:
            if i == prev:
                penalty += 5
            total -= penalty
    return total
```

```
>>> score(50, ['T','T','T','T','T'])
200
>>> score(10, ['T','T','F','F','T','T','F','F','F','F','T','T','T'])
125
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby()` and a little bit of math to compute the point values for each True/False streak:

```py
from itertools import groupby

t_score = 10
t_increment = 10
f_score = -5
f_increment = -5

total_score = initial_score
for key, items in groupby(result):
    length = sum(1 for item in items)
    if key == 'T':
        total_score += t_score * length + (length * (length - 1)) // 2 * t_increment
        t_score += t_increment * (length - 1)
    else:
        total_score += f_score * length + (length * (length - 1)) // 2 * f_increment
        f_score += f_increment * (length - 1)

print(total_score)
```

This outputs:

```py
125
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep tracks of the points, rewards and penalties using the dictionaries. And loop over your `result` list to reach to the final score.

```
initial_score = 10
result = ['T','T','F','F','T','T','F','F','F','F','T','T','T']

point_dict = {'T':10, 'F':-5}
increment_dict = {'T':10, 'F':-5}
cycle_num = 0


for i in range(len(result)):

    if not cycle_num:
        initial_score += point_dict[result[i]]
    else:
        if result[i] == result[i-1]:
            point_dict[result[i]] += increment_dict[result[i]]
            initial_score += point_dict[result[i]]
        else:
            initial_score += point_dict[result[i]]

    cycle_num += 1

print(point_dict)
print(initial_score)
```